# unexpected behaviour from conversion from long long to int

Tags: c++, casting

I'm working on VS2019, in windows 10 64bit.
I was doing some try and I tried the following code

```
int main() {
    unsigned long long ull = 70000;
    unsigned int ui = ull;
    std::cout << ui;
}
```

I would expect to get an output different from 70000, because 70000 is bigger then then the biggest number that an int variable can store. so why do I get `70000` as output? how is that possible?

Comment: *"70000 is bigger then then the biggest number that an int variable can store."* - Don't know where/how you concluded that, but clearly its not a reliable source. Check UINT_MAX and/or `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()`

Comment: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/, I used this site for checking UINT_MAX but I didn't see that it consider an uint as a 16bit variable

Comment: First, use [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits). It's probably *the best* documented language site. Second, you'll find it defined in `<climits>`, though for c++ I strongly advise using `<limits>` and printing, in your code, `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()`. It will deliver you the correct value and you can see for yourself what the cap on your platform is for `unsigned int`. Even on cpluplus.com it clearly says "65535 (216-1) **or greater**"

Comment: Here is a better page about [C++ fundamental types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types). Note the integer ranges can depend on the system.

Answer (score -2):

A 32 bit unsigned int can store values from 0 to 4,294,967,295.

Comment: Integer sizes are platform-specific. You cannot count on `unsigned int` always being 16 bits or always being 32 bits.